# Connect two components octoberCms backend

Tags: drop-down-menu, components, backend, octobercms

cannot find a way to connect two component together. I have table in first component, and need to get the list from second and show it as drop down list. Any chance I can do it? Thanks

P.s. forget to mention. I need to get a list in back end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getOptions()` method:

```
public function defineProperties()
{
    return [
        'country' => [
            'title'   => 'Country',
            'type'    => 'dropdown',
            'default' => 'us'
        ]
    ];
}

public function getCountryOptions()
{
    // here you can use DB or Model
    return ['us'=>'United states', 'ca'=>'Canada'];
}
```